# Optimization: use list of functions in tm_map wrapped into content_transformer

Tags: r, apply, tm

Is there a better / faster way than doing this:

```
funcs <- list(tolower, removePunctuation, removeNumbers, stripWhitespace)
for (i in funcs) myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, content_transformer(i))
```

I know, there exists *tm_reduce*, yet I cannot use this, as I need to pack the functions in the tm content_transformer.  Otherwise all meta-data will be destroyed.

I have tried something like

```
## wrap content_transformer around tm_reduce calls
helpFun <- function(x, args) content_transformer(tm_reduce(x, args))
myCorpus <- tm_map(myCorpus, helpFun, myCorpus, funcs)
```

but failed.

I have already thought about using do.call, funprog or apply.

Both funprog and apply disqualify in my opinion, as these functions are not meant to be used with a list *of functions* alike above.

Yet an efficient solution to this problem would be nice, since in each and every call of the for loop the whole myCorpus is called and saved again ... there has to be a better way!

*If you need sample data pls tell me.*